# PyPI package: found module but no type hints or library stubs

Tags: pypi, mypy, python-typing

I just made my first python package and uploaded it to PyPI (https://pypi.org/project/pygraphsearch/).

I then made some test code that uses it. I ran `pip install pygraphsearch` to download my package. Everything works fine except mypy complains that "found module but no type hints or library stubs".
I used typing everywhere in my package, so I don't know why it complains about that. What am I doing wrong?

#### Update

I added a `py.typed` file, like it says on https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installed_packages.html#making-pep-561-compatible-packages, but it still doesn't work.

I also added the `package_data` parameter in the call to `setuptools.setup` in `setup.py`.

```py
package_dir={"": "src"},
package_data={"pygraphsearch": ["py.typed"]},
```

My file structure in case it's relevant looks like this:

```
pygraphsearch
├── pyproject.toml
├── py.typed
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── pygraphsearch
        ├── Edge.py
        ├── Frontier.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── IterativeDeepeningFrontier.py
        ├── Node.py
        ├── search.py
        ├── Stack.py
        ├── State.py
        └── UndirectedEdge.py
```

Comment: You do install the `py.typed` file with your package, right?

Comment: Ok, I see that you published a new version that installs `py.typed`. So if you use this version, you still get the same message for this module, is that true?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen yes, but i think the problem was that the py.typed file was in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

I moved the file `py.typed` into `src/pygraphsearch` and that seemed to solve the issue.